# Rails 3.2.13 active_admin undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

long time lurker first time stander-upper-question-asker.

I just started a new rails project, running on Rails 3.2.13 and ruby 2.0. 
It's technically a clean install. Only gems I've added are pry and activeadmin + the needed metasearch, sass-rails and coffee-rails. After following active_admin setup instructions and the belongs_to paragraph.

```
    /app/admin/houses.rb
ActiveAdmin.register House do
  sidebar "Details" do
    ul do
      li link_to("Bookings", admin_house_bookings_path(house))
    end
  end 
end

/app/admin/bookings.rb

ActiveAdmin.register Booking do
  belongs_to :house
end
```

And now when I visit houses, I get the error message in rails s terminal.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `house' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::SidebarSection:0x007fb8b0989a98>):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
  app/admin/houses.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  app/admin/houses.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Like said previously, I have made no customizations to rails new app. I understand that when I visit /admin/houses, that there indeed is no variable house, because no house is selected yet. But also, there is no sidebar, so that should not be relevant.

I tried the link without 'house', like Zippie suggested, but ran into error "No route matches{:controller => "admin/bookings" }
And also, here's my rake routes http://pastebin.com/i48mVr0e

Comment: If you say there is no `house` in there, did you try just `admin_house_bookings_path`?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but that didn't work, I've added new info to my post, regarding to your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a different way to do it, not as pretty and generic but here's the code

```
ActiveAdmin.register House do
  sidebar "Details" do
    ul do
      li link_to "Bookings", "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}/bookings"
    end
  end..
end
```

And for ruby sake, I've moved the 3 requests to a function in helper.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where a nested model would not create a valid link. Try the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register House do
  sidebar "Details", :only => :edit do
    ul do
      li link_to("Bookings", admin_house_bookings_path(params[:id]))
    end
  end
 end
```